# How could I bind a SolidColorBrush's Color property in a ResourceDictionary to a ViewModel Color property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I have a wpf `Window` that is using a `ResourceDictionary` that has a `SolidColorBrush` defined in it.

I can choose what color to set the `SolidColorBrush` as with it's Color property, by using the hex values like so:

```cs
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0000"/>
```

When I try to set it like this:

```cs
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding UserSelectedColor}"/>
```

It will obviously not work because a `ResourceDictionary` does not have a `DataContext` to set.

I tried to do this because I thought that maybe the Binding would use whatever `DataContext` is set on the `Control` that is using the `SolidColorBrush`, but that doesn't seem to be working.

So I'm wondering how am I supposed to get the `Color` from the `ViewModel` if I can't set the `DataContext` of the `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: do you want it only in ResourceDictionary?

Comment: Are you trying to implement skinning?  Colors/brushes are usually View-specific things, not necessarily controlled by the ViewModel.  The ViewModel could define a flag which the View uses to determine which of a selection of brushes is used, if there is a fixed set of choices.

Comment: Can you just have your ViewModel expose a `Brush` rather than a `Color` and have elements bind directly to the property on the ViewModel?

Comment: I just tested this out using an external resource dictionary that is merged into a window's resources and it works for me.  Maybe you can post more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution would be to also put the ViewModel object into the ResourceDictionary and explicitly set the [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) of the binding:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UserSelectedBrush"
            Color="{Binding UserSelectedColor, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource UserSelectedBrush}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

It would however be easier to declare a `UserSelectedBrush` property of type `Brush` in the ViewModel and directly bind to that property:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding UserSelectedBrush}"/>
```

Comment: I ended up using what you said. I've never used the Source parameter of the binding before, so thank you for pointing that out.